# How do I get say to work?

Tags: perl

Im using Intellij 2016.1.1 and installed Perl plugin in it which work great.
I want to use **"say"** function and for that I added at the beginning of the script **use CORE**.

Though when I run the script (which use **say** function) it gives me the following error :

> can't locate CORE.pm in @INC (you may need to install the CORE module) (@INC contains: C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib C:/strawberry/perl/vendor/lib C:/strawberry/perl/lib .) at C:\Users\ngampel\IdeaProjects\itizik\myTestScript.pl line 4.

I tried looking online how to add module **CORE.pm** to intellij but coudln't find.

Comment: Where did you get that _use CORE_ from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do that. There is no **CORE.pm** that you can load. To get [`say`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/say.html), you need to do one of the following.

- Load the `say` feature explicitly at the top of your program

  ```
  use feature 'say';
  ```
- Turn on all *feature* features of Perl 5.10 or higher at the top of your program

  ```
  use v5.10; # or v5.12 or something higher
  ```

  But only as high as your Perl version. Run `perl -v` to see which version you have. This might also turn on other features. Make sure to check [the perldoc for feature](http://perldoc.perl.org/feature.html).
- Reference `say` directly from `CORE::`.

  ```
  CORE::say 'Hello World!';
  ```

All of those will work and are explained in the [perldoc for `say`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/say.html). I prefer the first option.

---

A fourth alternative is to add `-Mfeature=say` to the arguments of your Perl interpreter (or path to perl, or similar) in IntelliJ. I don't know how to do that, though. **But then your programs will not work on other computers**, or if you run them outside of your IDE.

Comment: Isn't invoking with `perl -E` a fourth possibility?

Comment: @mark in general, yes. But you cannot do that for stuff a file run from OP's intelliJ I believe. So probably not applicable here.

Comment: The `-E` command-line switch is equivalent to a `use feature ':all'`, and @simbabque you're looking for `perl -Mfeature=say -e 'say "hello"'`, which is fine

Comment: @Borodin you're right of course. The comma would have been for multiple arguments. My bad.